# What is the halachic source for Achdut Yisrael?

Tags: halacha

The concept of Achdut Yisrael is often addressed from a spiritual and emuna perspective - for example the 4 minim being symbolic of achdut yisrael.

In this respect I ask 3 separate yet related questions:

1. Is there a halachic source/ mitzvat aseh/ derabanan for "achdut yisrael"?
2. Is there a halachic source/ mitzvat aseh/ derabanan  to be individual within shevatim and minhagim - behezkat - "Ish be'diglo" ?
3. Would "Lo titgodadu" be a mitzvat lo taaseh for not being mekayem achdut Yisrael?

Comment: Re. 3 Lo Sisgodedu has nothing to do with Achdus. Two Beis Dins in the same city can argue whether one is a Mechalel Shabbos or did a Mitzva

Comment: @Shmuel Those are two different Achduts.

Comment: Can you source this interpretation of the 4 Species?

Comment: @DoubleAA re species: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20324

Comment: See the beginning of the Sefer HaMspik of R. Avraham Ben HaRambam where he describes the "private path" which consists of all "inyanim" (for lack of a better word) that are gradational. i.e. one can do more or less of them. For example, one can always love God more, but one cannot shake lulav more; either one has shaken it and fulfilled his obligation, or not. This category includes mitzvos d'oraysa, but also the taamei hamitzvos, their underlying themes, lessons we learn from chachamim, etc., (ayin sham). It is clear from his formulation that these are not optional, although they arent...

Comment: Formally listed as Biblical or rabbinic mitzvos. It seems likely that were there an inyan of "achdut yisrael" that it is to this category that it would belong.

Comment: The source for the 4 minim being a semel of Achdut is in the Vayikra Raba 
במדרש ויקרא רבה )ל, י"ב( נאמר:
"פרי עץ הדר אלו ישראל: מה אתרוג זה יש בו טעם ויש
בו ריח - כך ישראל יש בהם בני אדם שיש בהם תורה
ויש בהם מעשים טובים; כפות תמרים אלו ישראל -

Comment: Of course Lo Titgodedu has nothing to do with Achdut.   But it is related in the sense that a shul that splits into 2 minyanim at the same time and place is over on Lo Titgodedu and therefore not makayem a mitzvah of Achdut - if there were such a mitzvah.

Comment: So now I see the Natziv on Parashat Noach regarding Dor Hapalaga - the Natziv says the the Torah did not specifically mention what was their averah - because it was unnecessary.   The Netziv stresses the importance of plurality of opinion - 

כאשר עשו לאברהם אבינו. נמצא שהיו "דברים
אחדים" שביניהם לרועץ, שהחליטו להרוג את מי שלא
יחשוב כדעתם

Comment: @DoubleAA Another source for the symbolism of achdus in the 4 minim can be found in the Divrei Yoel's understanding of the Kalir's piyut written for yom rishon of Succos. It can be found in the Zemiros Divrei Yoel on moadim, but it is taken from his sefer on Chumash. I will try to find the source in Divrei Yoel on chumash soon. (TBH, it's really just in the words of the piyut, you don't need to go looking for the Divrei Yoel).

Comment: The piyut is called אקחה בראשון, and the shtickle from the Divrei Yoel is sourced in my bencher at תשי"ב יום א.